# Left Menu disappers in some pages

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

In Joomla platform I’ve an application that I desire to modify. 
The following link is the application: http://www.simbios.com/mombaers-verbeke-law/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5&Itemid=136 . 
In option “Team” in the menu, I Added an item "Bruyninckx Isabelle" that when I click it, the left menu disappears, but it shows me the selected article, however, if I select another item such as "Jos MOMBAERS" in the menu on the left side, it doesnt disappear the left menu and shows the selected information.
I did the following activities previously
1 .- I created in Joomla the article and the category "Bruyninckx Isabelle" and associated it to the section "Team".
2 .- In the option "Menu Item Manager" I  attached the article "Bruyninckx Isabelle."

What do I require to do that the behavior be same in all of these items in this menu?

Comment: Is your side-bar menu is a module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to go to the module manager and add your new menu item to the list of pages which will display the module(s) in question.

'Extensions' -> 'Module Manager' -> (click on module)

Use CTRL + mouse button to add pages to the selected group which will show the module.

Repeat this for each module that you wish to see on the resultant page.

NoNumber.nl has an 'advanced module manager' that may help you to avoid such 'micro-management' of your modules.